# Using DbContext in a Class in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am having trouble calling my class when trying to use the database in the class.  I have my context setup as so

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users {get; set;}
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }
}
```

I try to access my database in the class using this method

```
private AppDbContext db;

public PasswordManager(AppDbContext db)
{
    this.db = db;
}
```

The problem that I'm running into is when I try to use that class and do something like `new PasswordManager()` it wants a parameter sent for the db in the constructor.  What am I doing wrong?  I don't want to pass the database as a parameter, but I need to use the database in the class for data.  Should I be using a `using` statement instead when in a class?

Comment: Do you want to use the class manually or resolve it from a DI/IoC container?

Comment: It can be called from anywhere. Not sure what best practice is

Comment: If you have a class with a constructor with parameters, you must pass arguments for those parameters if you want to instantiate that class... You cannot get around this with `using` statements, why would you think so? So you need `new PasswordManager(new AppDbContext())`. But `AppDbContext` has a non-default constructor as well, so `new PasswordManager(new AppDbContext(new DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>()))` and so on. If you don't want that, then you must wire up your dependency injection so that it knows `PasswordManager`, and inject `PasswordManager` into classes where you want to use it...

Comment: In the controller I have arguments in the constructor so I figured it was the same.  I'd prefer not to have to pass the context. is there a way around that?

Comment: @Magnetron because then how would the `PasswordManager` get a reference to a `AppDbContext`?

Comment: _"is there a way around that?"_ - yes, that's called dependency injection. Go read [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1). You just need to register your `PasswordManager` with your DI framework, and inject it in the constructor of the controller where you want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use dependency injection, you must use dependency injection all the way. That means not using `new` directly. In order to inject the dependencies, the DI container must be responsible for instantiating it. If you instantiate it, then nothing will be injected.

Long and short, you need to register `PasswordManager` with the service collection (if you haven't already) and then inject `PasswordManager` into wherever you're using it, rather than newing it up yourself.